# Write multiple values to different csv columns in jython

Tags: csv, jython

Using SOAtest, I'm trying to get three values to write to different columns in a csv.

SOAtest currently writes all vales to one column and 'stacks' them together.

In SOAtest I'm using 3 utilities within the test tool:

1. XML transform tool (it grabs XML element values)
2. An Extension tool (this allows jython script to organize values grabbed in #1)
3. Write File Tool. (This points to a folder and creates the csv)

In step #2 here is the code that writes out to #3.

```
def output(input, context):

return (str(input) + '\n')
```

Is it possible to change the 2 lines of code to write to 3 columns?

I'd like to try and do it this way if at all possible.

Thanks!
djs

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a list of entries (lst in the code below), you could do it this way.

```
import csv

n = 3
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
csvwriter = csv.writer(open('/tmp/split.csv','w'))
for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
    csvwriter.writerow(lst[i:i+n])
```

If it is a string, you can always split it to convert it to a list.